Trying to assign a task created in a screen flow to a user
I am creating a screen flow that creates a new record for a task and assigns a contact (specified by the user of the screen flow) as the owner (OwnerId) of the task. The contact who will own the task can vary based on who the user of the screen flow chooses, so whichever contact they select (using a picklist) is found in the database and assigned as the owner of the new task.
However, when I try to assign the contact as the owner of a task, I get a Field Integrity Exception error. I have found that I cannot set the OwnerId of this new task equal to the contact Id of the contact I want to assign as the owner of the new task without getting such an error.
I tried finding a task that was already owned by the contact and setting the new task's OwnerId field equal to the preexisting task's OwnerId (which in this case would be that same contact). This works, as it seems there is a difference between a contact in the form of its ContactId and its OwnerId, I am just not sure how to work around this without the method previously stated. In the future, tasks will be created using this workflow that need to be assigned to contacts that don't have preexisting tasks to reference their OwnerId's from.
If anyone could help me find a solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

What does the Field Integrity Exception say exactly

Here is the error:
"Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: 003PE00000F9qzdYAB. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide."
I've looked extensively at the links they gave and through other questions here without much luck.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  A contact record cannot own anything.  An owner has to be a User or a Queue.  Please [edit] your post to explain your use case and why you need to assign tasks to contacts rather than Users, especially if you expect those contact people to update and close the Task record itself.

@Ethantium Right, 003 is a Contact record. Task owners have to be Users. You might be thinking of WhoId (Name field on UI), that can be a Contact.

@identigral I understand where I went wrong, I failed to distinguish between Users and Contacts. In the case for my flow, I actually needed to assign the task to a User, not a contact. I was able to pull the user rather than the contact, which solved my problem. Thank you so much!
